# Getting first element of loop in blade

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get only first element which is presented in the loop. So if I have something like

```
@foreach($entries as $entry)
@if($element == 1)
     // do something
@else
     // do something else
@endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use loop.first [more information here](http://robin.radic.nl/blade-extensions/directives/foreach.html)

```
@foreach($array as $key => $value)
     @if($loop->first)
           // do something
     @else
           // do something else
     @endif
@endforeach
```

*By default, blade doesn't have @break and @continue which are useful to have. So that's included.*

*Furthermore, the $loop variable is introduced inside loops, (almost) exactly like Twig.*

> loop.first True if first iteration

There is other way also like this but you'll have problems if there is not element starting with `0`

```
....
if($key == 0)
....
```